# settingup load balancer server in IBM Websphere environment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, networking, routes, websphere

I am using websphere network deployment. I have written an application that is deployed on two different nodes on the same cell. Now I want to load balance the two servers with sticky session option. Is there a way we can create load balancer server within the websphere environment? I have seen an option called On demand routing, is that equal to load balancer? Your help on this is much appreciated. Btw I am using websphere 8.5.x. thanks.

Comment: Look at this technote http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21219567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the On Demand Router is the native load balancer for a WebSphere cell.  Then you simply use the "weight" feature to control the distribution of requests.

**Setting Weight** -
In the admin console, go to "Servers > Clusters > [your cluster type] > [your cluster name]" then under the "Additional Properties" heading click "Cluster members".

Set their "configured weight" to equal values and then ripplestart the cluster (or cycle individually). Note, "runtime weight" takes effect immediately but is reset to configured weight whenever the server is started.

Requests are allocated by a simple formula: (weight of Member X) / (Sum of all member weights)

so if server A has a weight of 20 and server B has a weight of 1, then server A should get 20 / (20+1) or 95.3% of all requests.

In your case, just set them to the same weight.

Comment: I also want to know that the web servers can be deployed in different geo location and have a load balancer to route the requests. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on connection between the ODR and worker nodes, that should be fine.  Just watch the SystemOut logs for communication errors.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic HTTP load balancer is the included Apache-based webserver (IHS) and the WAS WebServer Plug-in.  Network Deployment also includes a low-level IP sprayer to allow a cluster of webservers to be managed safely.